# Add data to angular $http cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

When using angular [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you can set the request configuration `cache` property to `true` and the response will be stored. Next time the same request is made, the response is served from the cache without sending a request to the server ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching)).

How do you add a (key,val) pair to this cache without performing the http request?

I want to do something like

```
cache.put("/api/country/uk", someData)
```

and when `$http.get("/api/country/uk")` is called later, the cached data is used instead of making the http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://www.ng-book.com/p/Caching). Will keep the question + answer if someone else needs it.

You can get the cache by

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
```

and then you can put data to it like this

```
cache.put("/api/country/uk", someData)
```

When you call

```
$http.get("/api/country/uk", {cache:true})
```

you will get the cached response.